# Making crumpets in advance?

Tags: baking

My fiancée lived in England for a few months a couple of years ago, and has spoken about crumpets ever since.

I've never tried them myself, but I'm planning on making a few for her breakfast on her birthday in a couple of weeks.

I found several recipes, but they all follow the same basic structure:

1. Mix stuff.
2. Let sit for about an hour.
3. Make crumpets in pan.

Step 2 is somewhat problematic here, I don't really have that hour.

Is there any way I could make the batter in advance?

Or could I make the crumpets in advance and reheat them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are better off making the crumpets in advance and then reheating them. The rising agent in crumpets is usually bicarbonate of soda or baking powder, and so the batter can't be 'held' in the fridge like a yeasted batter - it would be very dense if you left it too long.

So, make the crumpets, then reheat them. I'd suggest using the toaster - this is how crumpets are sold and prepared in the UK. Make sure you have plenty of salted butter on hand too!

Comment: I've never had clotted cream and jam on a crumpet. Always on scones. But then you are apparently from London, you're all a bit weird ;)

Comment: aagh, in my caffeine deprived state I read scones!

Comment: I prescribe crumpets!

Comment: Not getting woken up at 5:30 helps too.

Comment: Ah. I hear the bitter tones of a parent of children unaware of the intricacies of Daylight Savings Time.